# How to match current date and specific date in Python

Tags: python, string, multithreading, list, datetime

I'm developing a reminder app in Python. My question is when I execute my code. It should wait until current date equals to specific date. But it's not working, here's my code.

***CODE:***

```
from threading import Thread
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Current date, 8/15/2020 - 10:00
a = datetime.now()

# Specific date (1 minute later from current date), 8/15/2020 - 10:01
b = a + timedelta(minutes = 1)

# Reminder name
d = "stack reminder"

# Reminder list
c = {}

# Target function
def createThread():

    while True:
    
        if(b.second == a.second and
            b.minute == a.minute and
            b.hour == a.hour and
            b.day == a.day and
            b.month == a.month and
            b.year == a.year):
            print("worked")

            # If thread name in reminder list
            if d in c:
                print("canceling")
                t.cancel()
                break

# Set thread and thread name and print thread name
t = Thread(target = createThread)
t.setName(d)
print(t.getName())

# Append reminder name to reminder list and print
c[d] = b
print(c)

# Start thread
t.start()
```

This code isn't working. Is `if` statement wrong? I'm creating `Thread` because while program waiting for specific date, I want to do different things. Where is my fault and how to run this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are never updating the `a` variable again.

`datetime.now()` doesn't constantly update so you will have to call this in your thread.

`a = datetime.now()` in every iteration of your while loop.

At the moment you are never getting get your if condition to match as the time in `a` stays in the past.

Also you should be able to simplify this.

```
(b.second == a.second and
            b.minute == a.minute and
            b.hour == a.hour and
            b.day == a.day and
            b.month == a.month and
            b.year == a.year):
```

To just simply

```
if b == a:
```

As both should be datetimes.

But its probably better to do use > in your condition as by using == you would have to match to the millisecond. Even matching to the second could cause issues and the condition might be missed.

i.e

If "a" (i.e the current time) >= "b" the time you want to check for.
Then fire the condition.

or put another way... If the current time is greater than or equal to the calendar entry time - then its time to alert the user.

```
if a >= b:
```

Complete Example:

```
from threading import Thread
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Current date, 8/15/2020 - 10:00


# Specific date (1 minute later from current date), 8/15/2020 - 10:01
b = datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes = 1)

# Reminder name
d = "stack reminder"

# Reminder list
c = {}

# Target function
def createThread():

    while True:
        a = datetime.now()
        if a > b :
            print("worked")

            # If thread name in reminder list
            if d in c:
                print("canceling")
                t.cancel()
                break

# Set thread and thread name and print thread name
t = Thread(target = createThread)
t.setName(d)
print(t.getName())

# Append reminder name to reminder list and print
c[d] = b
print(c)

# Start thread
t.start()
```

Comment: You're the best, I'm looking for this answer for almost 2 days. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: A small piece of advice, which someone gave to me once on here many years ago. Don't try to run before you can walk. Get the basics down first and come back to multi threading and more advanced topics later. You will have a much more enjoyable experience trying to wrap your head round these once you're core knowledge is solid.

Comment: Will do buddy. :)